# Django reputation / like system for public user profile - error 404

Tags: python, django

I'm beginning with Django. I try to use a like system for the public profile of my users. But I don't understand why I got an error 404. Do you think it's possible to use PK with OneToOneField for user?

user/models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reputation = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_reputation')
    ...
```

user/views.py

```
# public profile reputation
@login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login')
def ReputationView(request, pk):
    userprofile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST": 
        userprofile.reputation.add(request.user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))      
        
    @property
    def total_reputation(self):
        return self.reputation.count()
```

user/urls.py

```
path('reputation/<int:pk>/', ReputationView, name="reputation_public"),
```

user/templates/user_public_profile.html

```
 <form action="{% url 'user:reputation_public' user.pk %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="user_id" value="{{ user.id }}" style=""><img src="/static/img/like.png" width="20px" height="20px" class="" style="border-radius: 90px;background: #ffffff36;" title=""> {{current_user.userprofile.total_reputation}} cherries</button>
    </form>
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `user_id` to filter, since the `User` object and `UserProfile` object do not (per se) share the same id:

```
@login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login')
def ReputationView(request, pk):
    userprofile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user_id=pk)
    if request.method == "POST": 
        userprofile.reputation.add(request.user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))      
    # …
```

Comment: Thanks @Willem for your answer :) really helpful. error 404 is solved. But when I clic the there is not change on the total. Do you think there is something wrong on my template?

Comment: @Louis: no, I think you add it the other way around. If you wan to add the user to the logged in user, it should be `request.user.userprofile.reputation.add(pk)`, right now you add the current user to the reputation of the user with `user_id=pk`.

Comment: well thanks @Willem. I'll inspect why reputation does not upgrade when I clic on the button.

Comment: It works (+1 reputation) only for my public profile /profile/louis/ with my account (louis) but if I try on other public profile /profile/fredo/ with my account (louis) reputation does not change...

Comment: @Louis: but should `fredo` be added to the `reputation` of `louis`, or `louis` to the reputation of `fredo`?

Comment: Louis is a connected user. He just logs in... and he would like to give a + 1 reputation to Fredo (which public userprofile page is /profile/fredo/). Louis clics on the button. But Fredo's reputation does not change unfortunately (the bug is here). 
So louis to the reputation of fredo :)

Comment: But here you submit it with `{% url 'user:reputation_public' user.pk %}`, so with the logged in user as `pk`. You should use the `{% user 'user:reputation_public' other_user.pk %}` so where the parameter contains the id of the *other* user then.

Comment: thanks a lot @Willem, I made a stupide mistake :) 
<form action="{% url 'user:reputation_public' current_user.pk %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="user_id" value="{{ current_user.id }}" title=""> {{current_user.userprofile.total_reputation}} cherries</button>
    </form>